# Feeds bot posts announcements without user flair links

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

The bot posted [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8888/2019-community-moderator-election-results) in the appropriate channel but the links to the two users' profiles were lost in translation. Perhaps it needs a filter to replace the user flairs with just their names or similar?

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49447324#49447324